Is XYZ Euler rotation wrong ? Unable to observe stable axis when rotating on y and z axis in XYZ mode
Is something wrong with my understanding about euler rotation ? My understanding is that euler rotation revolve around the local axis. For example, if I rotate around X axis (moving local Y and Z axis). Then if I rotate around Y, I should be rotating around the new local Y axis. Some good example / playground is shown here https://www.mecademic.com/academic_articles/space-orientation-euler-angles/
But why when I change the angle value in transformation panel in blender that is not the case ?
https://youtu.be/7LyDptQoUCs
We can see from the video that when rotating Y, NO axis are stable!

The "stable" axis depends on the Euler order.  Only the first Euler axis is stable; with objects' default XYZ orientation, that means the X axis, unshown in your video.  By "stable", I mean that changing the X rotation won't change the direction that the transformed X axis is pointing.  There are two ways to talk about Eulers, that are mathematically identically but talk with reversed orders, so you may be comparing what somebody says in one perspective with a reversed perspective.

If you have a mathematical expression $(5 + 3) × 2$ and you increase $3$ by one to $4$, you don't expect the result to increase by one as well, right? You can think of an Euler rotation as 3 rotations in the specified order: effectively then, your first rotation is rotated by your 2nd rotation, and both are rotated by your 3rd rotation. So only the last rotation will linearly (circularly ) translate to the resulting rotation.

See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/appendices/rotations.html#axis-angle-mode

In a gimbal, it is the axes of rotation that are effectively in a hierarchy. They do not generally follow the axes of the transformed object.
The Euler notation: ('XYZ' 'YXZ') etc. places the lowest in the gimbal-hierarchy first.. i.e. grandchild, child, parent.
I suspect you want to see each rotation, when executed in XYZ order, spin about the transformed axis of the object. That will happen in a 'ZYX' hierarchy:

It will not happen in 'XYZ', because the X rotation will not pull round the Y and Z axes of rotation:

To get your head round Euler rotations, I thoroughly recommend playing with them with the Transform Orientation set to 'Gimbal' and the rotation gizmo visible, as in these illustrations. Then you can see the effective 'parenting' in the gimbal, (internally, the result of the order of matrix multiplication)
Gimbal Lock occurs when the child drags the grandchild in exact line with the parent, losing a degree of freedom.
